# AWS Architecture of CPU intensive MySQL searching and querying

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, scaling

I'm posed with a simple problem of scaling. As college students, we are new to setting up AWS services, droplets, scaling etc. We are stuck at deciding the architecture of our app. I'm unable to decide whether to use a big computing AMAZON EC2 or smaller multiple instances for benchmarking performance.

Even after code optimization, our MySQL queries are not as fast as we want it to be and clearly our hardware will address this problem. We are looking for high performance servers which require mostly searching a lot of MySQL FULL INDEXED search queries over 1.3M records (which clearly is a CPU and Memory intensive task). We intend to switch over to Solr at a later point of time. Both these tasks are very CPU demanding and RAM dependent. As of now, we are running our web app stack entirely on a single CPU with 2 cores and 4 GB RAM. However, we now wish to split the load up into multiple, say 5 instances/droplets of each 2 cores and 4 GB RAM.

Our primary concern is that, If we did create multiple ec2 instances/ droplets, wouldn't there be a considerable overhead for communicating between the instances/droplets for a standard MySQL search. As far as I know, the MySQL connection uses sockets to connect to local/remote host. Being a remote communication between 4 servers, I would expect significant overhead for EACH query.

For instance, let's say I've setup 4 instances and I've been allocated these IP's for each of them.

> Server 1- x.x.x.1
>
> Server 2- x.x.x.2
>
> Server 3 - x.x.x.3
>
> Server 4 - x.x.x.4

I setup a MySQL server and dump my databases into each of these instances (sounds like a very bad idea). Now I make a MySQL connection using python as:

```
conn1 = MySQLdb.connect(host=server1,user=user,passwd=password,db=db)
conn2 = MySQLdb.connect(host=server2,user=user,passwd=password,db=db)
conn3 = MySQLdb.connect(host=server3,user=user,passwd=password,db=db)`
conn4 = MySQLdb.connect(host=server4,user=user,passwd=password,db=db)
```

Since, each of these databases arn't on the localhost, I would guess that there is a huge overhead involved in contacting the server and getting the data for each query.

**My Thoughts:**

- I'm guessing there must be a solution for integrating different droplets/ instances together. Unfortunately, I haven't found any resources to support that claim.
- I've looked into Amazon RDS, which seems like a good fit. But again, I wouldn't be able to benchmark against a 4 instances MySQL search or a single huge AWS RDS server (given, it is quite expensive for new apps.)
- We are also unsure of replacement of python with popular languages for scaling such as **Scala** which will help me tackle this problem of dealing with multiple servers.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated by our 3 member team :)

Comment: Multiple copies of a database running on multiple servers will not do anything to speed up the execution of any single query...  *"(which clearly is a CPU and Memory intensive task)"* seems to overlook the fact that such a task could easily be disk-bound, not CPU, unless there is sufficient memory and appropriate configuration so that the entire working data set fits into the InnoDB Buffer Pool and thus requires no disk I/O.  Scaling the database *up*, not *out* may be more viable, depenending on exactly what you're trying to solve, which is actually still a bit unclear.

Comment: Thanks @Michael-sqlbot that was helpful. I was trying to run tests using `htop` and `top` while running my scripts. From that data I noticed that the CPU usage peaked in both the cores. The RAM was used only about 1/5th more. And there were no bytes written to the disk, as per the tool. Which is why I, I made that conclusion. However, it is true that the speed of the query is not improving. But at the same time I want to utilize MySQL's concurrency abilities to its maximum.